# How to attach text to the left of arrows / how to move arrows individually

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tsx

I am using arrows to filter the selected titles. Right now I have it implemented where the arrows are above the right part of the selected titles, however I can't attached the filter variables "popularity" and "release" to the left of these arrows.

Additionally, I want to shift some of the arrows over a few pixels to make it look nicer (I have attached comments in the code `Filter.tsx` to specify more information.

```
/*Filter.tsx*/
import React, { useState } from "react";
import VideoList from './VideoList.tsx';
import { VideoBoxProps } from "../interfaces/VideoBoxProps.tsx";
import './Filter.css'
interface FilterProps {
    onFilterChange: (filteredVideos: VideoBoxProps[]) => void;
}

export function Filter({ onFilterChange }: FilterProps): JSX.Element {
    const [videos, setVideos] = useState<VideoBoxProps[]>(VideoList())



    function parseDate(dateString: string): Date {
        return new Date(dateString);
    }

    function filterVideos(popularity: boolean, high: boolean) {
        let sortedVideos;

        if (popularity) {
            sortedVideos = [...videos].sort((a, b) => {
                return high ? a.popularity - b.popularity : b.popularity - a.popularity;
            });
        } else {
            sortedVideos = [...videos].sort((a, b) => {
                const dateA = parseDate(a.release);
                const dateB = parseDate(b.release);
                return high ? dateA.getTime() - dateB.getTime() : dateB.getTime() - dateA.getTime();
            });
        }
        setVideos(sortedVideos);
        onFilterChange(sortedVideos);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="horizontally-centered-container">
                <div>
                    <div className="img-name">Popularity</div>
                    <div className="arrowu" onClick={() => filterVideos(true, false)}></div>
                    <div className="arrowd" style={{/*Shift right 10px*/}} onClick={() => filterVideos(true, true)}></div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div className="img-name">Release</div>
                    <div className="arrowu" style={{ /*Shift right 10px*/ top: '27%'}} onClick={() => filterVideos(false, true)}></div>
                    <div className="arrowd" style={{top: '26%'}} onClick={() => filterVideos(false, false)}></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

```
/*Filter.css*/
.container {
    position: relative
}



body {
    background-color: #ebe5e5;
}

div.arrowu {
    width: 1.5vmin;
    height: 1.5vmin;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    left: 66%;
    top: 24%;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    
  
    &::before {
      content: '';
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border-width: .5vmin .5vmin 0 0;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #fafafa;
      transition: .2s ease;
      display: block;
      transform-origin: 100% 0;
    }
  
    &::after {
      content: '';
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      top: -100%;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border-width: 0 .5vmin 0 0;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #fafafa;
      transform-origin: 100% 0;
      transition: .2s ease;
    }
  
    &:hover::after {
      transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(-0.5px);
      border-color: orange;
      height: 150%;
    }
    &:hover::before {
      border-color: orange;
      transform: scale(.8);
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1068px){
    div.arrowu {
        left: 85%;
    }
}
  
  div.arrowd {
    width: 1.5vmin;
    height: 1.5vmin;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    left: 70%; 
    top: 23%;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
  
    &::before {
      content: '';
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border-width: .5vmin .5vmin 0 0;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #fafafa;
      transition: .2s ease;
      display: block;
      transform-origin: 100% 0;
    }
  
    &::after {
      content: '';
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      top: -100%;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border-width: 0 .5vmin 0 0;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #fafafa;
      transform-origin: 100% 0;
      transition: .2s ease;
    }
  
    &:hover::after {
      transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(-0.9px);
      border-color: #00ABE7;
      height: 150%;
    }
    &:hover::before {
      border-color: #00ABE7;
      transform: scale(.8);
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1068px){
    div.arrowd {
        left: 90%;
    }
}

  
  .horizontally-centered-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 66%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

```
/* SoloProjects.js, where the Filter is implemented */
import { React, useState } from 'react';
import VideoList from '../components/VideoList.tsx'
import { Grid, Container } from '@mui/material';
import VideoBox from '../components/VideoFile.tsx';
import { Filter } from '../components/Filter.tsx'
import './Page.css';

export default function Solo() {
  const [videos, setVideos] = useState(VideoList())
  const arrayToGrid = (arr, elementsPerRow) => {
    const result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += elementsPerRow) {
      result.push(arr.slice(i, i + elementsPerRow));
    }
    return result;
  };
  const handleFilterChange = (filteredVideos) => {
    setVideos(filteredVideos);
  };
  const videoGrid = arrayToGrid([...videos], 3);

  

  
  

  return (
    <div className="gradient_background_projects">
      <div className="title">Solo Work</div>
      <br />
      <br />
      <Filter onFilterChange={handleFilterChange}></Filter>
      <br />
      <Container maxWidth="md" style={{ marginTop: 16 }}>
        <Grid container spacing={3}>
          {videoGrid.map((row) =>
            row.map((vidData, idx) => (
              <Grid key={idx} item xs={12} sm={4}>
                <VideoBox {...vidData} />
              </Grid>
            ))
          )}
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[The Current Page status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tQqR.png)

I tried creating a container to place the text to the left of the arrows but failed.
I also tried just landing the text to the left of the arrows but that also failed.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).